# Rails devise with devise_token_auth is not showing the login form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-token-auth

Hi Iam trying to use devise along with devise_token_auth.

Initially my App was API only app. Hence we generated the app using --api flag. But after we need to add rails views for our admin functionality. As of now all the controllers are inherited from `ApplicationController` which is inherited from `ActionController::API`. Hence I created a new controller called `AppController` and inherited it from `ActinController::Base`. I started inheriting from the `AppController` for all my newly created controllers. All my newly created controllers are inside my `admins` namespace.

This is my `routes.rb`:

```
require 'sidekiq/web'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'

  devise_for :users, as: :admins, controllers: { sessions: 'admins/sessions' }

  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth',
    controllers: {
      sessions: 'api/v1/sessions',
      passwords: 'api/v1/passwords'
   }
  namespace :admins do
    # my admin routes
  end

  ###...

end
```

Here I have routes for the requests coming from API (handled by devise_token_auth) and for normal requests coming I added devise_for :users, as: :admins as shown above.

My `admins/sessions_controller.rb`:

```
  class Admins::SessionsController < ::Devise::SessionsController
    def new
      super
    end

    def create
      super
    end
  end
```

I generated the devise views and added in `admins` folder inside `views`

My `AppController`:

```
    class AppController < ActionController::Base
      before_action :authenticate_user!
    end
```

Here comes the issue, whenever I try to access any page it should redirect me to sign in page. But it just only displays me the following error

`You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.`

The entire page is blank and it is not showing any sign in form. I created `sessions/new.html.haml` page and placed inside the admins folder in my views.

`server log`:

```
Started GET "/admins/locations/4/bookings/pending" for 172.18.0.1 at 2018-04-26 09:06:34 +0000
Processing by Admins::BookingsController#pending as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"4"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Please let me know if you need any more info

Comment: The request is being served as HTML so the Devise setup looks correct. Have you checked your routes? Are they setup correctly? Also is there anything in your layout which can prevent the sign-in form from appearing?

Comment: Hi @JiggneshhGohel I think the routes are fine. As you pointed out, I commented my entire application.html.haml and to my surprise it still shows the error "you need to sign in or sign up before continuing". when I inspected this error is appended to the whole body tag of the page. I am not able to figure out the issue.

Comment: Are there multiple layouts in your application? That's a flash message which Devise renders when encountering an unauthorized request. In server logs you should be able to see which all views are being rendered to serve the request. In that you should find the layout file too.

Comment: There is only one layout. There are no other layouts or pages rendered. you can find it in server log.